# How do you test an "out of memory" exception handler on an Android device?

Tags: android, memory, exception, out-of-memory

I've just added an exception handler to handle an OutOfMemoryError when doing some image processing, because there have been a few crash reports of it happening.  Can I somehow fill up the memory on the device to test this?  If not, how else do I test that I am handling this properly?

Comment: Use really big images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can setup recursive calls to a function. That may lead to a `StackOverflowException`. Haven't tried in the emulator though.

Answer (score 0):

Just start allocating data on an ArrayList:

```
List<Bitmap> data = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

while(true){
  Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(1000,1000,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
  data.add(b);
}
```